# Where is the reward page on global link?

Tags: pokemon-global-link

I'm trying to find the reward page on global link and can't find it for the 2017 International February Challenge. Where exactly would it be?

Answer (score 1):

A link to the reward should show up in time (after you've logged in, of course).
If you're impatient, you can used this link: https://3ds.pokemon-gl.com/present/5263f699-dfcc-4ba9-a0a9-a0a4da05869b
`Source: https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/187276-pokemon-sun/75078834`